# at89s52 the right way to drive transistor

Tags: transistors, level-shifting

I want to ask about this configuration, the port is connected to at89s52 pin (not P0) and some of my friend say that this should work because the at89s52 have internal R that can replace the external Rb is that true?
please give us scientific answer

[image: is this OK]

Comment: Please use capitalization and proper punctuation, it makes you look professional.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct, at least for ports other than port 0, which has no pullups at all. The current will not exceed about 50uA (except very briefly at the low to high transition) so you do need to make sure the collector resistor isn't too low value - 15K might be a reasonable minimum.

For all 'scientific answers' you should refer to the fine [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1919.pdf) where all the details are laid out for your perusal.

By the way, it's a reasonable guess that the internal pullup is not a a "resistor" but rather a MOSFET designed to have a low Idss.

---

Edit: For those unfamiliar with "classic" (aka old as dirt) microcontroller port structures such as the pseudo-bidirectional ports of the 80x51, here is what they look like:

[image]

Note the absence of any distinction between input and output modes. This is a simplified schematic, the internal pullup weak MOSFET is actually paralleled with a strong speed-up MOSFET which briefly switches on during low-to-high transitions.

---

To clarify where I got the 15K value-

The current out of the output when high will be a maximum of 50uA according to the datasheet \$I_{IL}\$ specification (in other words, it will always be less than 50uA). No typical or minimum is given.

I have assumed that minimum is 1/3 of that (17uA) as a rule of thumb so the collector current of Q1 (left transistor) should not exceed 333uA (forced β of≤20) and thus the load resistor for +5 should not be higher than 15K

Is this good design? Any time you depend on guesses like my 1/3 rule of thumb you are taking a risk. It would be better to invert the output and add a base resistor, and use a PNP so that the output actively sinks current when 'on'. That way the base current is guaranteed by specifications in the datasheet. The shown circuit will work however, given appropriate values. The determination of the appropriate values involves either educated guesses like mine above, or measuring each unit, neither of which is preferable in a professional design.

Comment: You should probably clarify that you're talking about using the port as an _input_, using the internal pull-up. The question never mentions this detail, and your answer does not make much sense if you don't know about pull-up resistors.

Comment: @pipe No, that's not what's happening here. For the benefit of others I added a brief description of what is going on. The pseudo bidirectional ports do not have a DDR(aka TRIS) register and are always outputs and inputs simultaneously.

Comment: Well, as long as you clarified _something_ I'm happy, even though it wasn't what I thought. :)

Comment: thanks you for your quick answer, I have read the datasheet and I can not find the value of internal R resistor(or i can not read it) if I am gonna used the pin to drive the external transistor how to count the IC=hfe*IB does the IB = 50uA? 
thanks you and forgive me English is not my primary language

Comment: That's because it's not really a resistor. The current will be a **maximum** of 50uA according to the datasheet \$I_{IL}\$ specification (in other words, it will always be less than 50uA). I have assumed that minimum is 1/3 of that (17uA) as a *rule of thumb* so the collector current of Q1 (left transistor) should not exceed 333uA (forced \$\beta \text{ of} \le 20\$ and thus the load resistor for +5 should not be higher than 15K.